# How to add a column resulting from groupby ()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['4338', '4466', '1024',
                                    '4338', '4338', '5548'], 
                           'Sensor': ['temp_sensor', 'temp_sensor', 'temp_sensor',
                                      'strain_gauge', 'light_sensor',
                                      'strain_gauge'],
                           'Material Qtd': [1, 3, 5, 9, 8, 1]})

       print(df)

       Code       Sensor        Material Qtd
       4338     temp_sensor          1
       4466     temp_sensor          3
       1024     temp_sensor          5
       4338     strain_gauge         9
       4338     light_sensor         8
       5548     strain_gauge         1
```

I'm doing some operations according to the df and creating the df2:

```
        df2 = df.groupby('Sensor').agg(Qtd_Code=('Code','count'), Sum_t=('Material Qtd', 
                                                                         'sum')).reset_index()

        print(df2)

             Sensor       Qtd_Code    Sum_t
         light_sensor        1          8
         strain_gauge        2          10
         temp_sensor         3          9
```

So, I create a new column that averages as follows:

```
        df2['Mean'] = df2['Sum_t'] / df2['Qtd_Code']

        print(df2)

           Sensor         Qtd_Code   Sum_t    Mean
         light_sensor        1         8       8.0
         strain_gauge        2         10      5.0
         temp_sensor         3         9       3.0
```

The results generated are as expected, but what I would like to do is return the average information generated to the original dataframe (df). That is, I would like the df output to be:

```
       Code       Sensor        Material Qtd      Mean
       4338     temp_sensor          1            3.0
       4466     temp_sensor          3            3.0
       1024     temp_sensor          5            3.0
       4338     strain_gauge         9            5.0
       4338     light_sensor         8            8.0
       5548     strain_gauge         1            5.0
```

Thank you.

Comment: try `df['Mean_'] = df.groupby('Sensor')['Material Qtd'].transform('mean')` ?

Comment: No need for a second dataframe. You can apply this direcly onto your dataframe. See the code given by @Anky. For more samples, have a look at [this](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/10/how-to-add-group-level-summary-statistic-as-a-new-column-in-pandas/)